# ffmpeg split file retains original length

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, mpeg

I've losslessly extracted 30m from a ~1.5h long video using the following `ffmpeg` command:

```
ffmpeg -ss 0 -t 00:30:00 -i in.mp4 -acodec copy -vcodec copy out.mp4
```

The split was successful and `out.mp4` was created with the first 30m.
However... even though the video stops after 30m, video players such as VLC and Windows Media Player show the video length as still being ~1.5h long, and so does Windows Explorer when the file is selected.

**How come the video length shown is different than the actual video length?

How can I adjust it so they will match?**

I'm on Win7 using ffmpeg 64bit static from Feb 10th 2015.
Also, here is the output of the process:

```
ffmpeg version N-69672-g078be09 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnu
tls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-
libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-l
ibrtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --
enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --ena
ble-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      54. 18.100 / 54. 18.100
  libavcodec     56. 21.102 / 56. 21.102
  libavformat    56. 19.100 / 56. 19.100
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5.  9.104 /  5.  9.104
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0000000000307fe0] overread end of atom 'colr' by 1 bytes
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'in.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42isomavc1
    creation_time   : 2015-02-11 15:31:12
    encoder         : HandBrake 0.9.8 2012071700
  Duration: 01:33:46.64, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2556 kb/s
    Chapter #0:0: start -0.160000, end 301.040000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 1
    Chapter #0:1: start 301.040000, end 600.560000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 2
    Chapter #0:2: start 600.560000, end 901.040000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 3
    Chapter #0:3: start 901.040000, end 1200.560000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 4
    Chapter #0:4: start 1200.560000, end 1501.040000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 5
    Chapter #0:5: start 1501.040000, end 1800.560000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 6
    Chapter #0:6: start 1800.560000, end 2101.040000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 7
    Chapter #0:7: start 2101.040000, end 2400.560000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 8
    Chapter #0:8: start 2400.560000, end 2701.040000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 9
    Chapter #0:9: start 2701.040000, end 3000.560000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 10
    Chapter #0:10: start 3000.560000, end 3301.040000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 11
    Chapter #0:11: start 3301.040000, end 3600.560000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 12
    Chapter #0:12: start 3600.560000, end 3901.040000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 13
    Chapter #0:13: start 3901.040000, end 4200.560000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 14
    Chapter #0:14: start 4200.560000, end 4501.040000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 15
    Chapter #0:15: start 4501.040000, end 4800.560000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 16
    Chapter #0:16: start 4800.560000, end 5101.040000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 17
    Chapter #0:17: start 5101.040000, end 5400.560000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 18
    Chapter #0:18: start 5400.560000, end 5626.640000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 19
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/smpte170m/bt709), 720x576 [SAR 768:715 DAR 192:143], 2391 kb/s, 25
 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-02-11 15:31:12
      encoder         : JVT/AVC Coding
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 159 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-02-11 15:31:12
    Stream #0:2(und): Subtitle: mov_text (text / 0x74786574)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-02-11 15:31:12
Output #0, mp4, to 'out.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42isomavc1
    encoder         : Lavf56.19.100
    Chapter #0:0: start 0.000000, end 301.040000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 1
    Chapter #0:1: start 301.040000, end 600.560000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 2
    Chapter #0:2: start 600.560000, end 901.040000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 3
    Chapter #0:3: start 901.040000, end 1200.560000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 4
    Chapter #0:4: start 1200.560000, end 1501.040000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 5
    Chapter #0:5: start 1501.040000, end 1800.560000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 6
    Chapter #0:6: start 1800.560000, end 2101.040000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 7
    Chapter #0:7: start 2101.040000, end 2400.560000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 8
    Chapter #0:8: start 2400.560000, end 2701.040000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 9
    Chapter #0:9: start 2701.040000, end 3000.560000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 10
    Chapter #0:10: start 3000.560000, end 3301.040000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 11
    Chapter #0:11: start 3301.040000, end 3600.560000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 12
    Chapter #0:12: start 3600.560000, end 3901.040000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 13
    Chapter #0:13: start 3901.040000, end 4200.560000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 14
    Chapter #0:14: start 4200.560000, end 4501.040000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 15
    Chapter #0:15: start 4501.040000, end 4800.560000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 16
    Chapter #0:16: start 4800.560000, end 5101.040000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 17
    Chapter #0:17: start 5101.040000, end 5400.560000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 18
    Chapter #0:18: start 5400.560000, end 5626.640000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 19
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 720x576 [SAR 768:715 DAR 192:143], q=2-31, 2391 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 90
k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-02-11 15:31:12
      encoder         : JVT/AVC Coding
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 48000 Hz, stereo, 159 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-02-11 15:31:12
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=45000 fps=5763 q=-1.0 Lsize=  590048kB time=00:30:00.00 bitrate=2685.4kbits/s
video:553577kB audio:35153kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.223870%
```

Here's the output of `ffmpeg -i out.mp4`:

```
ffmpeg version N-69672-g078be09 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnu
tls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-
libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-l
ibrtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --
enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --ena
ble-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      54. 18.100 / 54. 18.100
  libavcodec     56. 21.102 / 56. 21.102
  libavformat    56. 19.100 / 56. 19.100
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5.  9.104 /  5.  9.104
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'out.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf56.19.100
  Duration: 01:33:46.64, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 859 kb/s
    Chapter #0:0: start 0.000000, end 301.040000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 1
    Chapter #0:1: start 301.040000, end 600.560000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 2
    Chapter #0:2: start 600.560000, end 901.040000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 3
    Chapter #0:3: start 901.040000, end 1200.560000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 4
    Chapter #0:4: start 1200.560000, end 1501.040000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 5
    Chapter #0:5: start 1501.040000, end 1800.560000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 6
    Chapter #0:6: start 1800.560000, end 2101.040000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 7
    Chapter #0:7: start 2101.040000, end 2400.560000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 8
    Chapter #0:8: start 2400.560000, end 2701.040000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 9
    Chapter #0:9: start 2701.040000, end 3000.560000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 10
    Chapter #0:10: start 3000.560000, end 3301.040000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 11
    Chapter #0:11: start 3301.040000, end 3600.560000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 12
    Chapter #0:12: start 3600.560000, end 3901.040000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 13
    Chapter #0:13: start 3901.040000, end 4200.560000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 14
    Chapter #0:14: start 4200.560000, end 4501.040000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 15
    Chapter #0:15: start 4501.040000, end 4800.560000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 16
    Chapter #0:16: start 4800.560000, end 5101.040000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 17
    Chapter #0:17: start 5101.040000, end 5400.560000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 18
    Chapter #0:18: start 5400.560000, end 5626.640000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 19
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/smpte170m/bt709), 720x576 [SAR 768:715 DAR 192:143], 2519 kb/s, 25
 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 159 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
    Stream #0:2(eng): Subtitle: mov_text (text / 0x74786574)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SubtitleHandler
At least one output file must be specified
```

Comment: Please include the complete console output from your command. Which players specifically are you using?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard - see updated question :)

Comment: @LordNeckbeard - see second update at the bottom of the question :)

Comment: @LordNeckbeard - I'm hanging my hopes up, so please let me know even if you don't know the answer ;)

Comment: Does it make a difference if you remove `-ss 0`? What if you move `-t 00:30:00` after the input so it gets used as an output option instead?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard - yup, moving `-t` to after the input `-i` did the trick.. Write it as an answer and I'll accept it :)

Comment: btw, I see it as a design flaw. I think command arguments should be as order-agnostic as possible

Comment: Option placement does matter, but `-t` is both an input and output option, so I'd assume it wouldn't really matter. Perhaps you found a bug. Does it occur with all inputs, or just a certain one(s)? I can't duplicate the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @LordNeckbeard wrote in the comments, moving the `-t` flag to after the `-i` flag works:

```
ffmpeg -ss 0 -i in.mp4 -t 00:30:00 -acodec copy -vcodec copy out.mp4
```

Comment: Or use `-shortest` as an output option.  I think what's going on is `-t` maybe applies to only one of the streams in the input file, or something.